# Declaring Method with generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I was using generic types in C# and I am new to using generic types. So, right now I am stuck with a problem. I have some classes like these:

```
public class MyModel1
{
}

public class MyModel2
{
}

public class BaseClass<T>
{
}

public class ChildClass1 : BaseClass<MyModel1>
{
}

public class ChildClass2 : BaseClass<MyModel2>
{
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    //What will be the syntax of declaring this method
    //The syntax of the following method is wrong and incomplete. 
    //It's there just to give an idea about whai i want to do.
    public void MyMethod<T>()
      where T : BaseClass<..what to write..>
    {

    }
}
```

My question is what will be the correct syntax of declaring MyMethod if I want to call MyMethod like this:

```
MyMethod<ChildClass1>();
```

Comment: Did you mean `where T : BaseClass<T>` ? also method is missing return type or void.

Comment: Edited and added return type. And no, it looks like, `where T : BaseClass<T>` isn't what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you try to filter "MyMethod" so that T is a class of type "ChildClass ...".

You can add a generic parameter to your function like this:

```
public void MyMethod<T, U>()
where T : BaseClass<U>
{

}
```

But then you have to call MyMethod in that way.

```
MyMethod<ChildClass1, MyModel1>();
```

So it's quite complicated to use.

---

Another solution is to create a new "blank" class :

```
public abstract class  Base // mark it as abstract if you don't need to use it in your code
{
}

public class MyModel1
{
}

public class MyModel2
{
}

public class BaseClass<T> : Base //The class inherits the new class
{
}

public class ChildClass1 : BaseClass<MyModel1>
{
}

public class ChildClass2 : BaseClass<MyModel2>
{
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    public void MyMethod<T>()
    where T : Base
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was also thinking of the same thing (Creating another Base class) as a backup plan. I guess I will have to take this way for now, until I get a better hold of generics and find a better solution (IF there is actually any better solution).

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to mention the return type and adding `<T>` after the class name. For example, if the return type is void, you could declare the method as:

```
        public void MyMethod<T>()
      where T : BaseClass<T>
{

}
```

Comment: Edited and added return type. And no, it looks like, `where T : BaseClass<T>` isn't what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This will work (by which I mean it compiles)

```
public void MyMethod<T>()
    where T : BaseClass<MyModel1>
{ }
```

so does this:

```
public void MyMethod<T>()
    where T : ChildClass1
{ }
```

---

Further edit after reading your comment...

You can do this:

```
public class AnotherClass<TBaseClass, TModel> where TBaseClass : BaseClass<TModel>
{
    public void MyMethod(TBaseClass input)
    { }
}
```

I have a term for this, hopefully non-offensive. I call it The Generic Rabbit Hole of Madness. It's what happens when we try to combine generics and inheritance so that one set of classes can accomplish a broad set of goals that become increasingly confusing, and we solve it by adding more generic parameters and more generic classes.

You reach the bottom of the hole if you
- use `<dynamic>`
- check to see what the actual type is using `GetType()`, `typeof`, or `is`
- get it to compile but can't remember what it's supposed to do

Comment: Yes, they do work. But then I will need to write MyMethod for all MyModels (the 1st way) or for all the ChildClasses (the 2nd way). Which is why I was looking for something generic